# How to use SVGDocument in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dom, svg

According to the W3C recommendations, the method `getSVGDocument()`should return an `SVGDocument`, but the code in lib.d.ts is:

```
interface GetSVGDocument {
    getSVGDocument(): Document;
}
```

So how could I do that?

```
var svgDoc:SVGDocument= document.getElementById('myId').getSVGDocument();
var svgElement:SVGElement = svgDoc.getElementById("myElement");
... further manipulations on svgElement
```

More generally, do they passed by the SVG implementation in TypeScript or am I missing something?

Is there any proper implementation of the SVG DOM, or how could I implement it?

Answer (score 4):

The typescript `Document` type is comparable to an `SVGDocument`, so you should be fine to just use `Document`. You will need to ensure that your element is casted as the right type (`SVGElement` or `SVGSVGElement`).

Also, you can do double casting in Typescript. This may allow you to come up with a way to cast an element/document as `any` and back to the document/element type you need in the case that you run into further issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to the w3 spec SVGDocument implements Document and adds some stuff like `title`, `referrer`, `rootElement` and other stuff.
Those are all defined on the Document interface for TypeScript so you can already use it without changing anything.

The document.rootElement in TypeScript as in the w3 spec both return a SVGSVGElement.

Because TypeScript uses structural typing (and the types match here) you can use it right away.

edit: 
Because of the lib.d.ts is structured like this you do have the problem that you can do `document.forms` for example which you can't use on a SVGDocument which is a bit unfortunate because it does compile this way..